# Form value is not populating since coming from service

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am building a form in Angular 5 in a material popup with a select box and text fields. The select box value is coming from a service. But, the service is taking too much time and before that form comes, the user does not get the select box value. Only after some time does the select box value get populated. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you using `FormGroup` and `FormControl` to build your form? If yes, create your form when the subscription to your service returns a success, and in your template, show the form only if your `FormGroup` is instanciated.

Comment: yes, I am using fomControl.I am creating like that only but before that only view is getting ready and after some time dropdown value is coming.

Answer (score 0):

One way or another, you'll have to wait for the data to be fetched by your service.

If your problem is that the users would be able to use the select before the options are created, show the form only if everything is ready for use (or if you want to be more specific, show the select only if its data has been fetched).

In your component, where you get the data :

```
public showForm = false;

this.getDataService(param).subscribe((data) => {
    // All your logic here
    this.showForm = true;
}
```

And in your template :

```
<form [formGroup]="form" *ngIf="showForm">
    <!-- Your form template here -->
<form>
```

This way, your form won't show when the data hasn't arrived yet, and once the data has been fetched and the form has been completely build, the form will show up.

Alternatively, you could build your form only when the data has been fetched (this way, you'll loose the need for a boolean) :

```
public form: FormGroup = null;

this.getDataService(param).subscribe((data) => {
    // All your logic here
    // Here, controls is your array of FormControl.
    this.form = new FormGroup(controls);
}
```

and in your template :

```
<form [formGroup]="form" *ngIf="form">
    <!-- Your form template here -->
<form>
```